# JS/jQuery mailto AND loading other site

Tags: javascript, jquery, mailto, window.location

My situation is as follow:
I have the sites:
`preview.html` and `index.html`
Now I have some inputs and a button on `preview.html`, which should open the email programm using `mailto` and load `index.html` where `preview.html` was displayed

I have tried

```
window.location.href = "mailto:[myadress]?subject=[formname]&body[his inputs]";
window.location = "index.html"
```

Does anyone know how I could solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get client side - if the browser allows you is

```
window.open("mailto:[myadress]?subject=[formname]&body[his inputs]","_blank");
window.location = "index.html"
```

or using an iFrame:

```
window.iFramename.location="mailto:[myadress]?subject=[formname]&body[his inputs]";
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "index.html";
}),1000);
```

but a better solution is to mail at the server and redirect